# UIAlertView keyboard overlay textview issue

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uialertview

I have found this code:

```
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 130.0);
[myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];
```

But seems it want move up my alert to the top. How can I move up alert view to the top?

Set frame does not help as well. `alerView.frame = rect;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if you're using a `UIAlertView`. From the apple docs:

> ## Appearance of Alert Views
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of alert views.

else where....

> ## Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

and further..

> ## Using Auto Layout with Alert Views
>
> The layout of alert views is handled for you. You cannot create Auto Layout constraints between an alert view and another user interface element.

See [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) and [Alert Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView)

`UIAlertView` is also deprecated as of iOS8, so you should use `UIAlertController` instead. Or you could just make a custom `UIView` that does what you need it to do.