# Adding UItextField and UITextView to an UIAlertView

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uialertview

I have this code for showing alert view with two needed extra objects:

```
- (void)leaveCommentButtonPressed
{
    UIAlertView *leaveCommentAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Leave comment", nil)
                                                                message:@""
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 33)];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 33, 100, 67)];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    [view addSubview:textField];
    [view addSubview:textView];

    CGFloat system_version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (system_version < 7.0) //For Backward compatibility
    {
        [leaveCommentAlert addSubview:view];
    }
    else
    {
        [leaveCommentAlert setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    }

    [leaveCommentAlert show];
}
```

But my problem is that I can't calculate width of alertView to set width for my text view and text field.

Maybe there are some other answers how to achieve text field and text view. But my idea is to have `UIView` with appropriate size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to add UITextField to UIAlertView on iOS7...works in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549519/unable-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview-on-ios7-works-in-ios-6)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView keyboard overlay textview issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224859/uialertview-keyboard-overlay-textview-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Hic sunt dracones

> #### Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

You should use a alert view replacement. There are numerous in the web, for example: [CXAlertView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cxalertview), [DLAlertView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dlalertview) or [SDAlertView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sdcalertview)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to use a default implementation of `UIAlertView`, the Apple Docs also state:

> Optionally, an alert can contain one or two text fields, one of which can be a secure text-input field. You add text fields to an alert after it is created by setting its alertViewStyle property to one of the styles specified by the UIAlertViewStyle constants. The alert view styles can specify no text field (the default style), one plain text field, one secure text field (which displays a bullet character as each character is typed), or two text fields (one plain and one secure) to accommodate a login identifier and password

See [Alert Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView)

But, as mentioned in a different post, `UIAlertView` is deprecated and replaced by `UIAlertController`. Fortunately it comes with `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:` that allows you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: `UIAlertController` does not support adding text views, just text fields.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @rmaddy, I have a bad habit of reading those two as the same thing.